# How can I prevent Angular from re-sorting my list while editing?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, javascript-databinding

I created a little application using Angular to manage Todolists. Each list has a number of todos. Each todo has attributes name, value1 and value2.

Each list should be sorted automatically by Angular, so I used `ng-repeat="todo in selectedList.todos | orderBy: todoOrderFilter"`:

```
  <ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="todo in selectedList.todos | orderBy: todoOrderFilter">

      <div>
        <span>{{todo.name}} (Value1: {{todo.value1}}, Value2 {{todo.value2}})</span>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs" ng-click="editTodo(todo)"><i class="icon-trash"></i> Edit</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs floatright" ng-click="deleteTodo(todo)"><i class="icon-trash"></i> Delete</button>
      </div>

    </li>
  </ul>
```

In my controller I defined my order filter like this:

```
$scope.todoOrderFilter = function (todo) {
    return todo.value1 * todo.value2;
};
```

This works well so far until I tried to make each row editable. To accomplish this, I added an additional `<div>` with input elements to edit the values inside each `<li>` and also added `ng-hide="todo.editing"` and `ng-show="todo.editing"` to be able to turn on/off edit mode by simply setting `todo.editing=true` or `false`;

Full HTML looks like this:

```
  <ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="todo in selectedList.todos | orderBy: todoOrderFilter">

      <div ng-hide="todo.editing">
        <span>{{todo.name}} (Value1: {{todo.value1}}, Value2 {{todo.value2}})</span>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs" ng-click="editTodo(todo)"><i class="icon-trash"></i> Edit</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs floatright" ng-click="deleteTodo(todo)"><i class="icon-trash"></i> Delete</button>
      </div>

      <div ng-show="todo.editing">
        <input id="todoname" ng-model="todo.name" ng-enter="updateTodo(todo)" type="text" class="form-control marginBottom" placeholder="Todo speichern" aria-describedby="basic-addon2"></input>
        Value1: <input ng-model="todo.value1" ng-enter="updateTodo(todo)" type="text" class="form-control marginBottom" placeholder="Value1" aria-describedby="basic-addon2"></input>
        Value2: <input ng-model="todo.value2" ng-enter="updateTodo(todo)" type="text" class="form-control marginBottom" placeholder="Value2" aria-describedby="basic-addon2"></input>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="updateTodo(todo)">Save</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="cancelUpdateTodo(todo)">Cancel</button>
      </div>

    </li>
  </ul>
```

Edit button handler:

```
$scope.editTodo = function(todo) {
    todo.editing = true;
};
```

This kinda works but while I edit input fields for value1 or value2 my sort function is automatically triggered which causes the `<li>` elements to jump up and down which is really bad.

So what I basically want is that my auto sort filter is disabled while `todo.editing=true`.

So far I found these similar questions on SO but they weren't really helpful:

- [Disabling orderBy in AngularJS while editing the list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15290887/disabling-orderby-in-angularjs-while-editing-the-list) (Don't understand how to apply the answer there to my code)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30845516/stop-ng-repeat-auto-sorting-your-objects-while-editing-text-box-and-checkbox-in (No answer)

---

**Question:** How can I prevent Angular from resorting the todo list while `todo.editing=true`?

Comment: Setup a plunker with your code.

Comment: Instead of directly editing the object in your `ng-repeat` you could edit a copy of it and replace the original object when the user finishes editing.

Comment: @rob Yeah, that workaround did the job, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to edit a copy of the object instead of directly editing it. Then, replace the original object with the copy when the user finished editing.

Answer (score 0):

I firmly believe in utilising code that has already been written for us by the Angular team, and building upon it. As such, I think this is a perfect scenario for decorating the built-in `orderBy` filter to accept a fourth argument (`ignore`).

I haven't tested this myself very thoroughly but it should do the trick;

```
app.config(function ($provide) {
  $provide.decorator('orderByFilter', function ($delegate) {
    // Store the last ordered state.
    var previousState;

    return function (arr, predicate, reverse, ignore) {
      // If ignore evaluates to a truthy value, return the previous state.
      if (!!ignore) {
        return previousState || arr;
      }

      // Apply the regular orderBy filter.
      var order = $delegate.apply(null, arguments);

      // Overwrite the previous state with the most recent order state.
      previousState = order;

      // Return the latest order state.
      return order;
    }
  });
});
```

**Usage:**

```
<div ng-repeat="d in data | orderBy:predicate:reverse:ignore">

<!-- in your case -->
<div ng-repeat="todo in selectedList.todos | orderBy:todoOrderFilter:false:todo.editing>
```

I hope all of that makes sense (maybe even *just works™*).

Comment: Interesting, rob's suggestion to work on a copy did the job nicely though